# <p:ajax> from datatable to update a block

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

i have a selectBooleanCheckbox in a p:datatable, and i have an event when the value change.
I would like to update another pdatatable when there is an event. 
I am not able to update the second bloc .
here is the code :
Can someone help me to understand how the "update" in p:ajax works?

```
 <t:panelGroup layout="block"  id="aa">
                    <p:dataTable value="" 
                            var="var"
                            rows="20"
                            resizableColumns="true"
                            styleClass="borderless"
                            id="ee">

                        <p:column  style="text-align:left;width:100px;" >
                            <h:outputText value= "#{vocabularyBean.localizedMap.resourceLockAction}" />                     
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column  style="text-align:left ;width:400px;"  >
                            <h:outputText value="" />                           
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column  style="text-align:center; width:10px;">
                            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkboxId" value="#{BeanAlias.resourceLock}" >    
                                <p:ajax update="resourcePanelId" event="click" listener="#{bean.handleEvent}"/>  
                             </h:selectBooleanCheckbox> 

                        </p:column>



                    </p:dataTable>

        </t:panelGroup>


        <!--tableau --> 

        <p:panelGroup layout="block" id= "resourcePanelId">
                    <p:dataTable value="#{BeanAlias.itemsList}" 
                            var="var">

                        <p:column headerText="#{name}" style="text-align:left;width:100px;" >
                            <h:outputText value="#{bean.name}"></h:outputText>                              
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="#{bean.workerName}" style="text-align:left;width:400px;" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{bean.worker}" ></h:outputText>                                
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="text-align:center;width:10px;" id="hh">
                            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.siResourceLock}">
                            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                        </p:column> 

                    </p:dataTable>
        </p:panelGroup>
```

Comment: When getting an error message, you should not ignore it, but just use it as key to the answer. E.g., throw it into the input field of a search engine.

Comment: Thank you. i think the link you provide will help me to find the solution.